# Efficient data structure for storing dates/statuses in SQLite database?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, data-structures

I'm using **Django 1.10, Python 2.7,** and **SQLite3** to build a web app that keeps track of the status of an object and when it was last changed.

For example, every 24 hours, the user will import a list (such as the one below) of open ports for a host:

```
05/01/2017
==========
Host                Open-Ports
123.45.67.89        22, 80, 443
...                 ...
```

A port (or multiple ports) may close one day:

```
05/02/2017
==========
Host                Open-Ports
123.45.67.89        443
...                 ...
```

I want my Django app to display this data:

```
IPv4
   123.45.67.89
Ports
   22 [Closed on 05/02/2017]
   80 [Closed on 05/02/2017]
   443 [Open]
```

**What would be the most efficient way of keeping track of the status of ports?**

Currently, I have a Host model with the following fields:

- IPv4 Address (GenericIPAddressField)
- Host Name    (CharField)
- Location     (CharField)

What new field (and its type) should I add to accomplish this goal?

This information will be stored in a **SQLite3** database.

How should my SQL table be setup? How should I compare the dates to know when a port is closed? Will I need two tables to store today's info and yesterday's?

There could potentially be 100,000+ hosts, so I would need this method to be as optimized as possible.

Thank you!

**Clarification**:

I need to keep the date when the port was closed.
So if on the third day, we had:

```
05/03/2017
==========
Host                Open-Ports
123.45.67.89        22, 443
...                 ...
```

Then we'd see:

```
IPv4
   123.45.67.89
Ports
   22 [Open]
   80 [Closed on 05/02/2017]
   443 [Open]
```

Where port 80 still says it was closed on 05/02/2017.

Comment: What output do you want for ports which open and close multiple times? If you only ever want the most recent open and most recent close it would make the needed data more efficient.

Comment: if you don't want to keep track of hosts states (just want the most recent status, and old data is not important) don't keep them! simply update the host state in table and don't add new row for existing host, port.

Comment: your table should have a `status` field (close, open) so when user doesn't update status of a port you keep old status, if user closes a port, don't delete that row, just change `status` when user open a port if it exists just update the status

Comment: also you need to add `port_closed_datetime` field, (when user closes a port update this field, and when port is closed return the value of this field (ok use a better name for that field :-)) )

Comment: @aliva I appreciate the help! One question though; my table is for Hosts, not Ports, so what would be the best way to add a status field?
Should I create a `port_status` field in Hosts, make a dictionary of the info `{22 : 'open', 80 : 'closed', 443 : 'open'}`, and store that as a BLOB?